# SP.UI.Status.addStatus(str_var) throws an exception ''Strings is not defined'

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a such code

```
status = SP.UI.Status.addStatus(r_license_Full);
```

`r_license_Full` is a string from my resource file, and it gets its value normally
the problem is that this code works perfect in IE10 but not in Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in a delayed execution block like this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    status = SP.UI.Status.addStatus(r_license_Full);
}, 'sp.js');
```